# Is it always possible to replace "where" with "in which"?

Tags: relative-pronouns

I read on this site, that we put the words "in which" instead of "where". (Now I don't find the cite). Is that true?

Comment: It is good practice to use `in which` instead of `where` _in some cases_, but it isn't possible in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When *in which* is used to show location and introduces an independent clause, *where* can be used in substitute.

> The story *in which* the hero dies.
>   The story *where* the hero dies.
>
> Beautiful Hyde Park, *in which* people leisurely stroll.
>   Beautiful Hype Park, *where* people leisurely stroll.

However, it will not work with

> Unless it rains tomorrow, *in which* case we will go to the movies.

Comment: Peter, I edited your answer. Frankly your practice of bolding rather italicizing pertinent words and phrases makes your answers stick out like a sore thumb.