# where to use "where" and "in which"

Tags: pronouns

I am confused with the usage of "where" and "in which".

Is this because family is not a place.?

**Incorrect:** The survey showed that children are much more psychologically stable when raised in a family with two parents than in a family ***where*** only one parent cares for the child

**Correct:** The survey showed that children are much more psychologically stable when raised in a family with two parents than in a family ***in which*** only one parent cares for the child

Comment: Who says the first sentence is incorrect and on what basis? Can you show us a quote or link?

Comment: It is a question from "Manhattan Review GMAT Sentence Correction Guide [4th edition]" Question number 28 in which it states "where" is incorrect usage.

Comment: “Where” may appear imprecise and hence informal.

Comment: Is there any necessary that "where" should be used with only for places and not for situations

Comment: *where* mainly talks about **the place** and *family* is *not* a place! Which talks about 'choosing a type of family', and thus suits! ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the Manhattan Review GMAT Sentence Correction Guide doesn't know what it's talking about. There's nothing remotely "incorrect" about using ***where*** with "non-spatial" referent nouns such as ***family, company, academic field,*** etc. So the question is based on a false premise.

Comment: Here's the link that may help: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/where-versus-in-which

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it always possible to replace "where" with "in which"?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/86295/is-it-always-possible-to-replace-where-with-in-which)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think we should leave it open, and explain why the guide is wrong or give some guidance on using one over the other. I have a feeling that publication isn't the only place that might be inventing a rule like this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. In formal English, you would use *in which* because you are NOT referring to a place.  For example...

> The store where I purchased the flowers is now closed.
>
> Books in which vampires are the main characters are very popular.

However, in informal English, you will usually hear English speakers use *where* in both examples because *in which* sounds very formal.

The following link talks about the use of these two in regards to the GRE:
[where vs in which for GRE](http://www.kaptest.com/blog/grad-school-insider/2011/10/31/grammar-and-style-brush-up-relative-pronouns-in-which-and-when/)

Comment: This confuses me  because it could be read to imply that a *store* is not a place!

Comment: @AlanCarmack I'm not sure what you mean.  A store is a place, so we use "where."